# Make my own incrementing mysql id without auto increment

Tags: mysql, increment

How can I duplicate the function of an auto incrementing Id field without making the field itself auto incrementing? I suppose on my INSERT statement, I would need to somehow grab the last id created, and add +1 on the new entry. But I don't know how. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I ended up taking ypercube's advice and keeping the id field as autoincrementing and making my searchstring unique. Thanks!

Comment: Not wise - high race condition risks

Comment: You can use a `trigger`. When an `insert` is done on the table, it could `set` the `new.id` to the `max(of all previous ids) +1`. But as OMG safely advises, do this as an exersice only, not on production. Risks involved in doing yourself what the database should be doing.

Comment: Well I need another field to be my primary key, and any auto incrementing field has to be set as the key which is why I can't have my Id auto increment.

Comment: you could have the autoincrement field as primary key and your other field as `unique`.

Comment: @ypercube Should mention transaction requirements to avoid race-conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to select the highest current ID in one query, then use that when inserting using a second query.

To get round the race conditions, you could create a table lock (nasty) or use transactions (better, but not ideal)

Comment: This is inherently very bad. It will only work if these hold: 1) The transaction is SERIALIZIABLE [which requires that a transaction *over* the two statements is used; autocommit sucks] 2) It is okay if keys are skipped as a transaction may be rolled back.